# How to return selected value from a list in HTML

Tags: php, html

Here is my simple form..

```
<div id="new_data_Modal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"  >Update Profile</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <form method="post" id="update_form">
     <label>Username</label>
     <input type="text" name="user_name_update" id="user_name_update" class="form-control" readonly/>
     <br />
     
     <label>Access Locations </label>
      <select name="select2[]"  multiple="multiple"  class="form-control">
            <option value="11">Place 1</option>
            <option value="12">Place 2</option>
            <option value="13">Place 3</option>
            <option value="14">Place 4</option>
         
     </select>
     <br />
    
     <input type="hidden" name="employee_id_update" id="employee_id_update" />
     <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />

    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Currently from the access location list, I could select multiple items only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyImF.png)

[enter image description here][2]

What I need to do is, I need to allow users to select multiple items and then need to show them in a field with a comma seperated.
Ex:
When user select the place 1 and place 2, It should show in the textfield place1,place2 likewise. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: After form submission or as soon as the user made a selection?

Comment: As soon as user made a selection. Need to show all the places that can select and allow him to select one or more, then need to show selected all values in a comma seperated text